# native http post in ionic v4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

after i deployed my app on device " android " it wasn’t working proply because i used httpclient and i had problems with CORS .
now i am stuck for 5 days trying to do post request on native HTTP plugin! , take in mind I am using the same headers and data from the old code , but it keep telling me " You Must enter userID and pass" even though it is in the post request.

```
      {'withCredentials': 'true','accept':'*/*','accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate','content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8','user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
  } )
    .then(response => {
      // prints 200
      console.log(response),
      this.raw = response;}, err => {
        console.log('JS call err : ',err);
      });
```

the response status is :200 , but it is “You Must enter userID and pass” .
i tried changeing the user and pass methods but no luck .

first this is the console log of my post :

https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/7/c/7cd0165b56aabef6fbcb0340dd39238c5dd59bdd.jpeg

this is a post from the PC browser and it is OK to compare :

(https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/d/1/d190494f504d230396d3926e09a454d1230df05c.png

finally i did send post request to https://postman-echo.com/ which will return my payload just to make sure , this is the post :

https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/ionicframework/original/3X/3/9/3940194b8edd90b3ec8971f308d4ed2d7794ac97.jpeg

Comment: CORS are Server related Issue. you have to enable CORS on your server.

Comment: this is not CORS related , because i am using the native http plugin

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try **ionic-native-http-connection-backend** from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-http-connection-backend)

Answer (score 0):

To solve my perticular problem , 
what need to be done :

first disable the redirct

```
this.http.disableRedirect(true);
```

then catch err with new get request to redirect you to the page you want , as a cookie was already established

```
this.http.get(apiUrl2, {responseType: 'text'}, {});
```